# Meteor.users subscribe only return current user

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to get a user by the username, when I use `Meteor.users.findOne`, it always return the current user. And if I user `Meteor.users.find`, it returns all current user document, and the `profile.firstName` and `profile.lastName` of the right matched username.

```
Meteor.publish('userByUsername', function(username) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({
        username: username
    }, {
        fields: {
            'profile.firstName': 1,
            'profile.lastName': 1,
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get only the user that match with the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is not publish, but a method access to particular username. Publish/Subscribe is great for datasets that often change - say posts on stackoverflow, facebook feed, news articles, etc.

You are looking to get first/last name of a particular user, this does not really change. So what you actually want is to create a server method that returns the first/last name of the user. And you can call this method from the client to access this data.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  //get username var
  Meteor.call('findUser', username, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res.profile.firstName + " " + res.profile.lastName);
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.methods({
    findUser: function(username) {
      return Meteor.users.findOne({
        username: username
      }, {
        fields: {
          'profile.firstName': 1,
          'profile.lastName': 1
        }
      });
    }
  });

}
```

Notice that the client Meteor.call has a callback method. DB queries on Meteor server is asynchronous & non-blocking, so you need to access the result via a javascript callback function.

Comment: This works fine. It was a beginner mistake, now it's clear for me when user methods and public/subscribe. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

findOne finds and returns the first document that matches the selector. Publish method needs to return a cursor, you need to use find, instead of findOne:

```
Meteor.publish('userByUsername', function(username) {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        username: username
    }, {
        fields: {
            'profile.firstName': 1,
            'profile.lastName': 1,
        }
    });
});
```

Then you can call subscribe on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('userByUsername', 'bob');
```

And call `Meteor.users.findOne({ username: 'bob' });` in your helper for example.